# Why does my Image not load?

Tags: graphics

I've included some `.jpg` images in my LaTeX document. It won't load, even though the image is saved in the same folder as the main `.tex` documents.

[image]

### Edit 1

`ss.jpg` is currently saved in same folder as the the main `.tex` file.

### Edit 2

Added a preamble screenshot:

[image]

### Update

The issue has been resolved as a file name error. (See comments below)

Comment: Are yo using PDFLaTex? Then you can directly use Jpg and Png as image files. And you can control it: Open the PDF and look for your figures, if they are visible, everything is fine.

Comment: @Chris thanks, heres the thing, ive got the syntax right but the image wont load, where do i have to save my image file? in the same folder as the saved file right?

Comment: You can save your images basically everywhere you want to, but you have to tell LaTeX exactly where they are. Can you provide a MWE or at least the code you use?

Comment: @Chris ive updated do take a look

Comment: Are you using the `draft` mode?

Comment: Are you using `draft` mode by any chance? Switch to `final`.

Comment: @Christ Im using texmaker on mac, I just do a quick build and view as PDF, how do i switch out of the draft mode?

Comment: Can you please show you preamble and the code you use? This is actually like crystall ball reading and I am not very good at that :-)

Comment: Hey chris Ive added the preamble screenshot, the code that I use in the previous screenshot which i already edited in.

Comment: Adding this as real code (Which others can execute) would be more helpful. Also: The preamble is everything between `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`.

Comment: @Chris i think the my questoin hasnt been updated for you, i did upload the pre amble screenshot, i can see the \usepackages code in the question above lol

Comment: You don't show us the documentclass line, and honestly I think it's better if you copy-pasted the code into your question, rather than posting screenshots. Do you have `\documentclass[draft]{...}`?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I hope this one is right lol, it shows the documentclass line now!

Comment: I don't think there is anything in your screenshots that would make this happen. It would be helpful if you created a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and pasted that code into your question (not as a screenshot).

Comment: Two thoughts: (i) the image placeholders are square.  If the original images aren't square, it means that TeX is not finding the image files.  If the original images are square, either the above or TeX is in some form of draft mode.  (ii) If TeX is not finding the images, check that the filename matches exactly, including case.  MacOSX file systems have varying degrees of case insensitivity.

Comment: @Andrew, you nailed it! The file itself was saved as "ss" without an extension, i changed the it to ss.jpg and it worked. Im really sorry for misleading everyone!

Comment: Ah yes, the other nice feature of Mac OS X - its love/hate relationship with file extensions as vague hints on what is in the file.  I'd drop the question then.

Comment: The image file was saved without an extension and when changed the it to `image-name.jpg` and it worked

Comment: @Chris Thank you so much. I was using draft mode and you comment saved me a lot of trouble and time.

Answer (score 3):

Since the problem has been resolved, I'm putting the comments into an answer so that it is clear that the problem has been resolved.

Andrew Kerpert made the comment:

> If TeX is not finding the images, check that the filename matches exactly, including case. MacOSX file systems have varying degrees of case insensitivity

garciaj responded with the comment:

> you nailed it! The file itself was saved as "ss" without an extension, i changed the it to ss.jpg and it worked. Im really sorry for misleading everyone

Comment: Why did'nt you added this as a community wiki since you are not the answerer?

Comment: I briefly read the stack overflow blog [link](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/) and it says that the purpose of community wiki answers is to allow easy collaboration by making it easier for others to edit your answer. I am not sure in this case this answer needs any more input. But I am willing to consider why you think it should be marked community wiki.

Comment: As the answerer (well, trouble-shooter) I am quite happy for `I'd Like two Cod` to have the few points the answer may accrue before the question hits the bit bucket.   If only due to the sentiment in his/her user name.  (OT: I am only misspelling the user name to even the score - nothing personal.)

Comment: The link you posted says: "[A community wiki] post does not generate any reputation for anyone when upvoted or downvoted." Again, since you are not the actual answerer, it would be better to have your answer as a community wiki -- because of the handy property mentioned above. Moreover, it would reflect the collaborative character of your and @AndrewKepert s work. (Excuse my strange language in the first comment :)

Comment: Sure, why not then.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about `TeXmaker` but I suggest that you try to compile the following MWE to see if the image loads properly.

Download and save a file called `ibm.png` from [Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/200px-IBM_logo.svg.png).

In a folder, place the two files

```
hello.tex
ibm.png
```

The contents of `hello.tex` are

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{ibm.png}

\end{document}
```

Compile `hello.tex` using `pdflatex` in `TeXmaker`.
If this doesn't work, try using `pdflatex` in another program, e.g. `TeXworks` or `TeXShop` that comes with `MacTeX` or even the command line.

The output should be the following:

[image]

Comment: Where is the third answer?

Comment: What does your question mean? Was there a third answer?